# Pushing HTML checklist elements into an array with JS

Tags: javascript

I want my checklist to remember the value of the checked options. Whenever the user checks the box I want to push the value into the array, whenever he unchecks it, I want it to be deleted. 
With my submit button, I want to display an alert for every checked element.

I can fill the array, but for some reason it overwrites the previous elements. Also it just won´t react to the "unchecked-state", neither does it display anything on submit.
Note: I need this to work for about 200 inputs later.

```
<h1>Checklist</h1>

<form>
    <input type="checkbox" name="remember" id="remember" onclick="checkboxFunction(value)" value="F-Card geholt">F-Card geholt<br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="remember" id="remember" onclick="checkboxFunction(value)" value="Ersti Rally">Ersti Rally <br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="remember" id="remember" onclick="checkboxFunction(value)" value="TEST">TEST<br>
</form>

<script type="text/javascript">

    var checkbox = document.getElementsByName("remember");
    var checkboxArray = [];

    function checkboxFunction(value)
    {
        for(var i=0, length=checkbox.length; i<length; i++)
        {
            if(checkbox[i].checked)
            {
                checkboxArray.push(value);
            }
            else if (!checkbox[i].checked && value == checkboxArray[i])
            {
                checkboxArray.splice(value);
            }
        }
    }

    function alertFunction()
    {
        for(var i=0, length=checkbox.length; i<length; i++)
        {
            if (typeof checkboxArray[i] != 'undefined') 
            {
                alert(checkboxArray[i]); 
            }
        }   
    }
</script>

<input type="button" name="alert" value="Submit" onclick="alertFunction()">
```

Comment: checkboxArray is out of scope for your alertFunction.

Comment: I´ve tried to use it as public but it won´t work either, so I thought that might not be the problem. I´ve tried to find checkboxArray by ID, didn´t work either.

Comment: checkboxArray is defined in checkboxFunction so it's available only in scope of that function, not in the second one

Comment: I´ve tried what I tried 2 hours ago again and suddenly it worked... well I can display the elements in the array now, but it still overwrites them. The first one works, the second entry deletes the first and the second and the third overwrites all three with it´s value...

Answer (score 0):

move  `var checkboxArray = [];`
outside the checkboxFunction function

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        var checkboxArray = [];
    function checkboxFunction(value)
    {
        var checkbox = document.getElementsByName("remember");


        for(var i=0, length=checkbox.length; i<length; i++)
        {
            if(checkbox[i].checked)
            {
                checkboxArray.push(value);
            }
            else if (!checkbox[i].checked && value == checkboxArray[i])
            {
                checkboxArray[i] = null;
            }

            //alert(checkboxArray[i]); 
        }
    }

    function alertFunction()
    {
        for(var i=0, length=checkboxArray.length; i<length; i++)
        {
            alert(checkboxArray[i]); 
        }   
    }
</script>
```